# Auth0 Single Sign On wordpress is not wroking

Tags: wordpress, single-sign-on, auth0

I am using Auth0 for login purpose I integrated one wordpress website with the main web application. once the user logged in the main Web application.The user will automatically login using SSO feature of auth).

For SSO in auth0 i am using following URL

```
https://mysite.auth0.com/authorize?client_id=adgjgdasdjadjbv&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://dev.mysite.com/?auth0=1&state={"redirect_to":"http://dev.mysite.com/newpage"}
```

http://dev.mysite.com

is my WordPress site. In this wordpress aim using `Wordpress Auth0 Integration` plugin for configure aith0 client id and client secret.

i done this SSo for wordpress website 2 months before my application.At that time it's working perfectly. But now I take my wordpress website after main web application login its is redirection to auth0 login page.

I don't know what is the actual issue.Because i didn't changed anything on my code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell a lot from your information but I can ask this: have you checked on your Auth0 account dashboard that the URL:

```
http://dev.mysite.com/newpage
```

is listed under 'Approved Callback URLs'? To get to this, log in to Auth0, and on the Dashboard, click 'Apps/APIs', then click on the name of your App for your Wordpress site.